# Merging two json format based on

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js

I am trying to merge json format (prefably using underscore) but not sure how it could be done. The first json has no indicator of _id to be mapped.

JSON 1:

```
{
    "0001": {
        "answer": "sad"
    },
    "0002": {
        "answer": "sad1"
    }
}
```

JSON 2:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "0001",
        "question": "who am I"
    },
    {
        "_id": "0002",
        "question": "How old are you?"
    }
]
```

Final Result after merging:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "0001",
        "question": "who am I",
        "answer": "sad"
    },
    {
        "_id": "0002",
        "question": "How old are you?",
        "answer": "sad1"
    }
]
```

For the approach, i am trying to transform JSON 1 to following format first but unable to achieve.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "0001",
        "answer": "sad"
    },
    {
        "_id": "0002",
        "answer": "sad1"
    }
]
```

Comment: As easy as `arr.map(o => {
    o.answer = obj[o._id].answer;
    return o;
})`. But I didn't tried anything.

Comment: Please take a look at **JSON 1** it is not an array.

Comment: @Fabricio yes i am well aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you can do a foreach to add the new answer element:

```
var json1 = {
    "0001": {
        "answer": "sad"
    },
    "0002": {
        "answer": "sad1"
    }
};

var json2 = [
    {
        "_id": "0001",
        "question": "who am I"
    },
    {
        "_id": "0002",
        "question": "How old are you?"
    }
];

json2.forEach(function(o) { 
    o.answer = json1[o._id].answer;
});

console.log(json2);
```

I hope that helps :D

Comment: Sorry I've a typo in the code. Please check that I've replaced the **a** with **json1** inside it. It is working for me now.

Comment: @stackdisplay - `json1` is just a variable name. Remember JSON is just a standard JS object and can used like one.

Comment: @evolutionxbox  , you are right, the type of json1 is a standard object but if you take a look at the code I'm looping over `json2` with the forEach not over `json1` .... so .... 
`typeof json2.forEach === 'undefined'` is **false**. Again, please, check the code ;)